# Change source/content of a div dynamically with long blocks including scripts

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dygraphs

I have seen lots of questions & answers regarding similar issues, but I have not found answer for this particular case.

I have a `<div>` in the webpage where I show dynamically data into a graphic, it requires javascript into the `<div>` (using [dygraph](http://dygraphs.com/) library). I want implement a checkbox to change the content of the `<div>` between the graphic code and the code to show a live-webcam connection, which requires script too.

I have tried with `innerHTML` and jQuery function based on examples I have found, but all of them are referred to a very simple HTML changes without script content, the more complicated I have found is how to change a picture into the `<div>` content. I have read that `<div>` doesn't support src property, other forum says yes, in my case it has not worked. The library `div-src.js`,  doesn't work for this case too.

The other attempt was with `<iframe>` tag it has worked but page doesn't work properly and goes unstable, specially the websocket connection. Eclipse shows a warning  saying "unknown tag" and I have read that `<iframe>` is obsolete in HTML5.

I would like to perform this with jQuery but until know without success.

**What is the best method to insert dynamically into a `<div>` long blocks of HTML code with script, with calls to  js libraries?.**

```
<input type="radio" name="radiobutton" value="graph" onClick="changeDivContent()">
<input type="radio" name="radiobutton" value="video" onClick="changeDivContent()">

<div id="graph-video">
 --- Block with HTML, nesting divs and javascript ---
</div>
```

Note: With jQuery I have tried to use the [.load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function:

```
$( "#graph-video" ).load( "video.jsp" );
$( "#graph-video" ).load( "graphic.jsp" );
```

with the result: code for the graphic cause malfunction  and websocket close.

Comment: Finally it has worked. Thanks to the comments bellow. I have use the ".load ()" function. The way was to extract from each jsp file ( video and graphic) all the javascript code/functions. Then I have placed the javascript funtions in a js file, and this file is charged through the main page. In this way it runs.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
function changeDivContent() {
    $('#graph-video').html('<iframe width="420" height="345"src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/XGSy3_Czz8k"></iframe>)');
}
```

or with an external html File

```
$('#graph-video').load('external_file.htm');
```

Answer (score 1):

the way I see it you have various problems. First is loading js files dynamically. To do this you have to add them as DOM objects, not as inner HTML. For thi purpose you can use this function:

```
function loadjscssfile(filename, filetype){
 if (filetype=="js"){ //if filename is a external JavaScript file
  var fileref=document.createElement('script')
  fileref.setAttribute("type","text/javascript")
  fileref.setAttribute("src", filename)
 }
 else if (filetype=="css"){ //if filename is an external CSS file
  var fileref=document.createElement("link")
  fileref.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet")
  fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/css")
  fileref.setAttribute("href", filename)
 }
 if (typeof fileref!="undefined")
  document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref)
}
```

taken from [here](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/loadjavascriptcss.shtml).

As for the picture inside the div, it's heavily dependent on the type of picture you are referring to.

1. `<img>` inside a `<div>`:

   $('img_selector_here').attr("src", newSrc);
2. background property of a `<div>`:

   $('div_selector').css('background-image','url(img_url)');
3. `<canvas>` element, like the one produced by dygraph: Find a good tutorial for your specific needs, you can start by looking [here](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-element/), since the canvas element offers tons of options for drawing and redrawing.